# Binary Authorization for Cloud Run vs gcloud vulnerability filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

I have enabled automatic vulnerability scanning for my images in Google's Container Registry and was thinking now to use Binary Authorization to let my Cloud Run services only be deployed for images that pass a policy.

I read through the documentation https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/creating-attestations-kritis and so I need to create an attestor, use this kritis signer to sign an image and create attestations based on my policy and only then the Cloud Run service would be deployed.

I'm wondering if all of this is really necessary in my case.

In my Github Actions CI/CD pipelines I could use the gcloud command `gcloud beta container images describe HOSTNAME/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_ID@sha256:HASH --show-package-vulnerability` to view the vulnerabilities for a newly uploaded and scanned image and have my Pipeline fail if I find any vulnerabilities for a certain severity (e.g. critical) or even ignore certain CVEs before the Cloud Run service deployment with the new image. So I could basically achieve the same as the options available in the policy here https://github.com/grafeas/kritis/blob/HEAD/samples/signer/policy.yaml used by the kritis signer.

A gcloud command seems a lot simpler than implementing this whole process of using the kritis signer tool, creating attestations etc.

So are there any advantages or security reasons why I should use Binary authorization and follow that process instead of using the gcloud filter check in my CI/CD pipelines?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 different layers:

- On one side, you check that your container doesn't content any known vulnerability
- On the other side, Binary Authorization, you check that you deploy a container from an authorized registry

Imagine the case:

- You correctly check the container CVE in your CI/CD pipeline and you store it in your registry
- Someone deploy a container from another registry.

Even if you check YOUR container in YOUR registry, you doesn't protect Cloud Run against a deployment from another registry.

So, all your efforts are useless!

Comment: I see. Can you tell me where I can find your 2nd point in the documentation? How to set authorized registries in addition to checking for vulnerability issues? I know you can have an allowlist for exempt images but these images then ignore the rule that an attestation is required as I understand it.

Comment: I think I get it now. Because I'm creating only attestations for my images coming from my image paths it means Cloud Run can only deploy from those registries.